# My nupkg is incompatible with my Unified API app

Tags: xamarin, nuget

I've made a NuGet package that has a lib/Xamarin.iOS10 folder with a dll inside it.
I've created a test project (an iOS unified API Single View App) and I try to add my package but I get this response:

> Could not install package 'mypackage 1.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

Extracting the file, I can verify that my dll is present.

This is the nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="2.8">
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <title>My Package</title>
    <authors>Kristian</authors>
    <owners>Kristian</owners>
    <developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>
    <licenseUrl>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</licenseUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Experiment Package</description>
    <summary />
    <language>en-US</language>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Fody" version="1.29.3"/>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="../MyPackage.XamarinIOS/bin/iPhone/Release/MyPackage.dll" target="lib/Xamarin.iOS10/MyPackage.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Is there anything else I need to do? I am not using the new project.json format for my package.. I am using Xamarin Studio version 5.9.8.

Comment: Your .nuspec file looks OK to me. Can you publish your .nupkg somewhere? My only thought is that there is another version of the .nupkg somewhere cached which does not have the lib/Xamarin.iOS10/MyPackage.dll file.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

```
target="lib/xamarinios10/MyPackage.dll"
```

Instead of your Xamarin.iOS10 path?